# Can we create variables with '-' like JS in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a service that returns this JSON structure `"actual-price": {`,
I want to know if it is possible to create a variable like JS with Codable on swift.
PS: I can't change the JSON since the service is not mine

Comment: No, you will need to use `CodingKeys` to map the JSON to a property in your struct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use a `CodingKeys` enumeration to map the jSON properties to valid Swift properties.  Note that once you introduce a `CodingKeys` enumeration it must contain *all of the properties you wish to map*, not just the properties where you want to change the name.

Something like

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    var actualPrice: Double
    var quantity: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case actualPrice = "actual-price"
       case quantity = "quantity"
    }

}
```